# Angular 4 AOT compilation in hybrid app

Tags: angular, webpack, angular2-aot, ng-upgrade

Currently, I'm working on upgrading an AngularJS app to Angular 4, using the upgrade module.  With our current webpack config, it works fine, both in development and production.

When I added aot compilation through `@ngtools/webpack`, I got rid of all compilation errors, but there's a runtime error:

`Error: [$injector:strictdi] r is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode`.

This shouldn't be an issue, though, because I'm using `babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate`.  It only occurs when I add in the `@ngtools/webpack` loader; otherwise it works fine.

Here's the relevant section of the webpack config:

```
/* Loaders to handle scss, css, etc.*/

{test: /\.ts$/, use: "@ngtools/webpack"}, // Doesn't work
// Below lines work, if used instead of line above
//{ 
//  test: /\.ts$/,
//  loaders: ["awesome-typescript-loader", "angular2-template-loader"]
//},
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: [
    /node_modules/,
    path.join(__dirname, "src", "vendor")
  ],
  use: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"]
}
```

I also add in the aot plugin later on, but that's not what causes the issue.

And here's the entire .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "angularjs-annotate"
  ]
}
```